# website down in specific time period everyday when use heroku sslenpoint

Tags: ssl, heroku

My app can not be accessed only in time period from 6p.m - 2a.m (GMT + 7) everyday, others time is fine.

I added SSL Endpoint to application, and also configure the CNAME of domain  point to .herokussl.com.

Any suggestions please.

Thank you,
-Hoang

Comment: Have you tried to see if it's just down for you, or for everyone? - http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: This isn't nearly enough information to debug this issue.  Do you have evidence that it is related to the application code (the programming component) at all?  Does your application work when run locally?  Does your application work when run on a staging server that does not utilize an SSL endpoint or otherwise accessed without SSL?  What programming language is your app even written in?

Comment: I did monitor my app for the past 2 weeks and see that issue is still there sometimes. It's down for me but works well for my friends in different geographic, so I think it should be DNS propagation. The most strange is, it's only down on specific time ( for me ) and a month was not enough for DNS updated? This occurs for custom domain only, the default htts://<appname>.herokuapp.com still work without any issue.